# Centering bars on xticks in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, labels, bar-chart

My wife is working on her master thesis and we are trying to make some bar graphs to use with it. We have managed to create a nice-looking graph, but the labels/xtick does not align in center. When adding more addplots, things get even worse. 
We're both new to LaTex, and even after quite a few hours of browsing websites and manuals, I cannot find a solution to this problem.

My first try on a "MWE":

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10 cm}                                       
\begin{axis} [
symbolic x coords={Label 1,Label 2},        
xtick={Label 1, Label 2},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
axis lines=left,
y label style={rotate=-90},
ylabel=\Large{\textbf{\%}},                                 
title= \Large{Some Heading} ,               
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=1},                     
    ybar=0pt ,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=50,                                                
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    bar width=2.5cm,                                
    enlarge x limits={abs=3.2cm},   
]
\addplot [blue,fill=blue]                       
coordinates{ (Label 1,35.5) } ;
\addplot [red,fill=red]
coordinates{ (Label 2,14.8) } ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Please help us find a solution. Suggestions of other (simpler/better) packages to use are also welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

Is it like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10 cm}
\begin{axis} [
symbolic x coords={Label 1,Label 2},
xtick={Label 1, Label 2},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
axis lines=left,
y label style={rotate=-90},
ylabel=\Large{\textbf{\%}},
title= \Large{Some Heading} ,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    ybar=0pt ,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=50,
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    bar width=0.5cm,                       %% changed
    ybar=-0.5cm,                           %% new
    enlarge x limits={abs=3.2cm},
    nodes near coords,                     %% new 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},    %% new
]
\addplot [blue,fill=blue]
coordinates{ (Label 1,35.5) } ;
\addplot [red,fill=red]
coordinates{ (Label 2,14.8) } ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have marked the changes made in the code. I have changed the bar width to `0.5cm` (assuming that you may need it when more bars are added) and shifted them by the suitable amount so that `x tick` and `label`s align in the center by

```
bar width=0.5cm,                       %% changed
ybar=-0.5cm,                           %% new
```

I have also added the `y` values of the bars at the top by

```
nodes near coords,                     %% new 
nodes near coords align={vertical},    %% new
```

If you want `label`s also to be centered, you can use `xshift` and `yshift`s in

```
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east,
              align=center,xshift=0.4cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
```

Change the shift values appropriately.

Hope that is useful.